# Como gravar o que for recebido em uma porta do Apache direto no mySQL?

Tags: mysql, apache

Olá. Tenho um server `Apache` (XAMPP) e preciso receber mensagens de um dispositivo que manda mensagens para um IP e porta específicos. Gostaria de configurar o `Apache` para escutar uma porta (443, por exemplo) e gravar tudo que ele receber/escutar direto no `mySQL`, inserindo em uma tabela específica do banco de dados. Chamaremos o banco de dados de `DB` e a tabela a ser gravada é a `mensagens`, que possui os campos `codigo (INT, auto increment), mensagem (VARCHAR(200))`.

Isso é possível? Alguma sugestão?

Comment: O Apache nativo não faz isso. Me parece ser o caso de aplicação específica para a finalidade, via sockets (a não ser que você modifique o dispositivo para fazer requisições HTTP).

Answer (score 1):

O Apache implementa o protocolo HTTP. Se o seu aplicativo falar HTTP, pode falar com o APACHE. No lado do servidor, o Apache pode encaminhar a mensagem para uma CGI (em Python, Perl, etc) ou para uma linguagem (server side), como PHP ou ASP. Na CGI, PHP, ASP, etc, você pega na mensagem e escreve-a no MySQL.

Se realmente só quer enviar uma mensagem para um IP e uma porta, sem ter que usar o protocolo HTTP, o mais fácil é escrever um servidor em Python, Perl ou em Node.js. Eu recomendaria escrever um servidor em Node.js, pois consegue performances muito, muito boas, dado que é assíncrono.

Por exemplo, criar um servidor em node.js é tão simples como:

```
require('net').createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}).listen(7777);
```

Correndo o programa com `node servidor.js`, o mesmo fica à escuta na porta 7777. Este servidor não escreve a mensagem no MySQL (para ter apenas 5 linhas). Escreve só na consola o que recebe.

Um cliente pode-se ligar e enviar a mensagem. Exemplo de um cliente (também em Javascript):

```
var s = require('net').Socket();
s.connect(7777, 'localhost');
s.write('Oi!\n');
s.on('data', function(d){
    console.log(d.toString());
});
s.end();
```